# 500 internal server error for an elastic beanstalk application

Tags: jenkins, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

i have an elastic beanstalk application
when I created the sample application and deployed the code through Jenkins it was working fine
but after the latest deployment its giving a 500 internal server issue
after when i changed its application version and deployed the older version its working fine
but its showing the error for the latest deployement
can anyone please help
do I need to make changes in the configuration ?
code ?
pipeline?

the below is the logs of the environment if it can help

```
PublishLogs.log:

2023-03-03 07:06:01,617 DEBUG 1 PublishLogs - Log publication disabled. Exiting
2023-03-03 08:06:00,490 DEBUG 1 PublishLogs - Log publication disabled. Exiting

u_ex23030308_x.log:

2023-03-03 08:01:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:01:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:01:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:01:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:01:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:01:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:01:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:02:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 15
2023-03-03 08:02:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:02:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:02:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:02:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:02:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:02:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:02:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 15
2023-03-03 08:03:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:03:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:03:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 15
2023-03-03 08:03:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:03:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 15
2023-03-03 08:03:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 15
2023-03-03 08:03:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:03:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:04:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:05:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:05:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:05:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:05:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:05:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 0
2023-03-03 08:05:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 62
2023-03-03 08:05:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 62
2023-03-03 08:05:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 156
2023-03-03 08:06:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 124
2023-03-03 08:06:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 200 0 0 15
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2023-03-03 08:06:18
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2023-03-03 08:06:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 404 0 2 390
2023-03-03 08:06:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 404 0 2 46
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2023-03-03 08:06:33
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2023-03-03 08:06:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:06:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 15
2023-03-03 08:06:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:06:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:07:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 15
2023-03-03 08:07:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:07:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 15
2023-03-03 08:07:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:07:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:07:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:07:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:07:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 15
2023-03-03 08:08:32 172.31.44.200 GET / - 80 - 172.31.47.45 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/110.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:32 172.31.44.200 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - 172.31.47.45 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/110.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://paymentureapi-env-live.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:08:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:09:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:28 172.31.44.200 GET / - 80 - 172.31.90.111 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/110.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:28 172.31.44.200 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - 172.31.90.111 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/110.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://paymentureapi-env-live.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:10:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:00 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:15 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:30 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.47.45 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
2023-03-03 08:11:45 172.31.44.200 GET /swagger/index.html - 80 - 172.31.90.111 ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 - 500 21 13 0
```

I tried to change some application configuration which doesn't work
rebuild the environment also didn't work
run the pipeline many times its getting deployed successfully but the URL is not working